# Dango: What is "the proper successor to" pinax.notifications?

Tags: django, pinax

`pinax.notifications` is a nice package but it uses the decorator `@python_2_unicode_compatible` and it apparently still tries to get it from `django.utils.encoding` rather than `six`.

This is after running `pip3 install --upgrade pinax.notifications` just now.

Is there a more up-to-date package that I should be using now?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear you are thinking about moving on. We have a PR in the works for pinax-notifications that will drop EoL Python/Django versions and add the versions that are officially supported. The PR hasn't passed all the tests yet, but hopefully will soon. https://github.com/pinax/pinax-notifications/pull/94

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. I've published a pinax-notifications release today that drops Python 2.7 support. https://pypi.org/project/pinax-notifications/